# Is there a way to do TThread.Synchronize with Timeout?

Tags: delphi

Sometimes you need to call `TThread.Synchronize`, but also you can enter in a **deadlock** situation.

For example:

```
Thread1.execute
procedure
begin
  ....
  TThread.Synchronize(..)
  ...
end;
```

Then from the main thread doing something like:

```
Thread1.terminate;
Thread1.waitfor;
```

can leave to some deadlock because `TThread.Synchronize` will never succeed :( 
I would like to know the most easy way to handle such scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to use `TThread.Synchronize()` with a timeout.

You can use `TThread.Queue()` instead, passing it a procedure associated with a `TEvent` that you can wait on after `Queue()` exits.  Then the main thread can signal that `TEvent` when it processes the request (just be sure to not free the `TEvent` until after the main thread has used it, unless you call `TThread.RemoveQueuedEvents()` to cancel the request first).

That being said, what you describe is NOT a deadlock scenario.  If  `TThread.WaitFor()` is called in the main UI thread, it processes pending `Synchronize()`/`Queue()` requests while waiting for the thread to terminate.  If `TThread.WaitFor()` is called in another thread, then the main UI thread is free to process `Synchronize()`/`Queue()` requests normally.

Comment: Remy, i m happy that i asked, i didn't know that TThread.WaitFor() when called in the main UI thread, it processes pending Synchronize()/Queue() requests while waiting for the thread to terminate !! of course with this i will not have any deadlock ...